# Confirming whether the limit sum/difference formula should we apply here from beginning or not

Tags: limits

Suppose that we want to find limit of some function say $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}$$ $$(x+h)^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x+h})-(x-h)^2\sin(\frac{1}{x-h})$$

> If we expand the squares and make the function breaks into some other functions ( as it will get reduced to addition of some functions in this case ) so if we don't know from initially that the limit of the original function may exist . Then if we now use the sum formula of limit that the limit of a sum of functions is the sum of individual limits of the functions' sum, will it be the correct approach? Or we would have to make sure that each individual function has a limit (before moving onwards), otherwise the original function needs to be considered only to find limit (that is limit of sum formula will not be applicable here)? Like, for example, I did this in this function before : $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sin ^{2} x}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ x\neq 0$ you can take limit for each term separately conclude that then limit is $x^{2}\sin (\frac 1  x)-x^{2}\sin (\frac 1  x)=0$. For $x =0$ we get $\lim 2h^{2}\sin (\frac  1 h)$ and $|\sin t|\leq 1$ so the limit is again $0$.

Comment: Yeah so we need to know from early that for $x \neq 0$ we have the those functions separate limits existence hence we can solve with that. For x=0 we cannot say so hence we need to take combine function and solve like the case i gave below where i consider ( sin^2x - x^2)/(xsinx)^2 right ?

Comment: For $x=0$ also both the terms have limit $0$ so it is OK to take limits separately.  @ProblemDestroyer